# how to integrate 2 array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on an array which return true result for me but I am not familiar with array. I am doing the following way to return result.

This is my array :

```
foreach($getvote as $option){       
  $data['id'] = $option['option_id'];
  $data['option'] = $option['option'];
}
```

and when I `print_r` I get following answer:

```
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
        [option] => Array ( [0] => this is option 1 for id 2 [1] => this is option 2 for id 2 ) )
```

But I want to integrate this 2 array become like this which id as key and option as value :

```
Array ( [result] => Array ( [1] => this is option 1 for id 2 [2] => this is option 2 for id 2 ) )
```

Hope someone can give me some solution. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), like:

```
$final_array = array_combine($data['id'], $data['option']);
```

**Note:: array_combine():: Returns the combined array, FALSE if the number of elements for each array isn't equal.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = array()
foreach($getvote as $option){       
  $data['result'][$option['option_id']] =  $option['option']; 
}

print_r($data);
```